# Yii authorized access for a single column for update action

Tags: php, yii

In my web application I want to grant access rights for an  update action for one type of user only for a particular column only . I googled it for a long time but could not find a solution .How should I proceed?
  I have a table called producer offer which has a column called offered_qty.  There are  three  types of users,  producers, consumers and  admin.    Producers   should be able to   update  any column   but   consumers should be able to update only the column of   producer offer   table named    "offered_quantity".

My access rights function  for producer offer table

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array
        (
                array('allow', 'actions'=>array('bookOffer','update',), 'expression'=>'isset(Yii::app()->user->type)&&(Yii::app()->user->type==="CONSUMER")'),
                array('allow', 'actions'=>array( 'create','update','delete'),  'expression'=>'isset(Yii::app()->user->type)&&(Yii::app()->user->type==="PRODUCER")'),
                array('allow', 'actions'=>array('manage','createViaSms','view','myOffers'),'users'=>array('*')),
                array('deny', 'users'=>array('*'),),

        ); 
    }
```

My access rules for consumer requirement table

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array
        (
                array('allow', 'actions'=>array( 'create','delete','update' ),  'expression'=>'isset(Yii::app()->user->type)&&(Yii::app()->user->type==="CONSUMER")'),
                array('allow', 'actions'=>array( 'manage','view','myNeeds'), 'users'=>array('*'), ),
                array('deny', 'users'=>array('*'),), 

        ); 
    }
```

Comment: please post what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii `accessRules` control access to a `controller/action`. The standard Yii approach is to create one `update` action for each model/table.

But you want to control access to a column *within* a model.

So you have two choices:

1. Either create an `action` specifically for updating said column. And then use `accessRules` to control who can execute the `action`.
2. Or use one general update action for the model, but then *within* the action differentiate between user permissions.